# Why `volatile` makes no difference?

Tags: c, volatile

According to the Wikipedia site:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable

I copied its sample code for testing in my laptop, but the two have no difference! Here is my GCC version info:

```
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

The C source code is

```
/* volatile_var.c */
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
        /* in no_volatile_var.c there is no volatile here */
        volatile int a = 10, b = 100, c = 0, d = 0;
        printf("%d\n", a + b);

        a = b;
        c = b;
        d = b;

        printf("%d\n", c + d);
        printf("%d\n", a);
        return 0;
}
```

I compiled the no_volatile_var.c and volatile_var.c both with

```
gcc -S *.c
```

but the out is the same following

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .globl  _main
    .align  4, 0x90
_main:
Leh_func_begin1:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp1:
    subq    $32, %rsp
Ltmp2:
    movl    $10, -12(%rbp)
    movl    $100, -16(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -20(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -24(%rbp)
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    movl    -16(%rbp), %ecx
    addl    %ecx, %eax
    xorb    %cl, %cl
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdx
    movq    %rdx, %rdi
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movb    %cl, %al
    callq   _printf
    movl    -16(%rbp), %ecx
    movl    %ecx, -12(%rbp)
    movl    -16(%rbp), %ecx
    movl    %ecx, -20(%rbp)
    movl    -16(%rbp), %ecx
    movl    %ecx, -24(%rbp)
    movl    -20(%rbp), %ecx
    movl    -24(%rbp), %edx
    addl    %edx, %ecx
    xorb    %dl, %dl
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
    movl    %ecx, %esi
    movb    %dl, %al
    callq   _printf
    movl    -12(%rbp), %ecx
    xorb    %dl, %dl
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
    movl    %ecx, %esi
    movb    %dl, %al
    callq   _printf
    movl    $0, -8(%rbp)
    movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
Leh_func_end1:

    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str:
    .asciz   "%d\n"

    .section    __TEXT,__eh_frame,coalesced,no_toc+strip_static_syms+live_support
EH_frame0:
Lsection_eh_frame:
Leh_frame_common:
Lset0 = Leh_frame_common_end-Leh_frame_common_begin
    .long   Lset0
Leh_frame_common_begin:
    .long   0
    .byte   1
    .asciz   "zR"
    .byte   1
    .byte   120
    .byte   16
    .byte   1
    .byte   16
    .byte   12
    .byte   7
    .byte   8
    .byte   144
    .byte   1
    .align  3
Leh_frame_common_end:
    .globl  _main.eh
_main.eh:
Lset1 = Leh_frame_end1-Leh_frame_begin1
    .long   Lset1
Leh_frame_begin1:
Lset2 = Leh_frame_begin1-Leh_frame_common
    .long   Lset2
Ltmp3:
    .quad   Leh_func_begin1-Ltmp3
Lset3 = Leh_func_end1-Leh_func_begin1
    .quad   Lset3
    .byte   0
    .byte   4
Lset4 = Ltmp0-Leh_func_begin1
    .long   Lset4
    .byte   14
    .byte   16
    .byte   134
    .byte   2
    .byte   4
Lset5 = Ltmp1-Ltmp0
    .long   Lset5
    .byte   13
    .byte   6
    .align  3
Leh_frame_end1:


.subsections_via_symbols
```

According to Wiki's explanation, there should be difference and the volatile edition should bigger than the non-volatile one. I compiled them into binary and find that there size is also the same.

Questions:

- Does my llvm-gcc cause that?(latter I'll test these code on Linux) or the Wiki's explanation is error?
- Both them compiled the same binary code(simply according to their size), so their print result is the same. But according to Wiki's explanation, does the two print different screen output?

---

**Update**

This question is due to Wikipedia's error on optimization setting, and have no related with what the title says. Should I close this question?

Comment: Disable optimizations and try.

Comment: @asawyer:- `volatile keyword stops the compiler from performing optimization`

Comment: With optimization and no volatility, the compiler could read `b` once and assign the value thrice; with volatility and/or no optimization, the code will read `b` thrice — and I think that's what the assembler shown does.

Comment: @JesusRamos: OMG, I opened the O3 option, and it really make difference now(I have updated it)! I think the Wiki should update now! While there is no optimization option, the GCC would not optimize by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `gcc -O3` to turn on optimizations and you should see a difference.

Answer (score 4):

The volatile keyword is merely a hint for the compiler that an external thread might change this variable at any time, so it should be careful with optimizations which rely on the assumption that this won't happen. But your application doesn't have any other threads, so there is no reason to treat it differently.

You could try to compile the program with a higher optimization setting (-O3 command line parameter) - this could cause the compiler to do optimizations on the non-volatile version which are forbidden for the volatile one.

Answer (score 0):

If we declare variable as volatile, the compiler can not perform optimization.